# How to speed up CLI powershell command to replace text?

Tags: powershell, performance, batch-file, replace

I want to know if it's possible to optimize the following code to make the text replacement process in the CLI call faster.

Note: The actual file I want to replace text in is pretty large.

This is my code:

```
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Wolf=.*','Wolf=True') | out-string)"
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Bird=.*','Bird=True') | out-string)"
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Pig=.*','Pig=True') | out-string)"
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Fox=.*','Fox=True') | out-string)"
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Bear=.*','Bear=True') | out-string)"
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Elephant=.*','Elephant=True') | out-string)"
powershell -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -encoding utf8 $test) -replace ('^Monkey=.*','Monkey=True') | out-string)"
```

I have read about the `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines` operator but I wasn't able to implement it into my CLI call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- PowerShell CLI calls ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)  are *slow*, so you should generally strive to make *as few as possible*.

  - One way to do that is to consolidate multiple calls into one.
  - If the resulting `-Command` argument gets too long / unmaintainable, save the commands to a script file (`*.ps1`) instead, and invoke it via `-File`
  - A way to potentially speed up any given CLI call is to place `-NoProfile` before `-Command` or `-File`, which bypasses [profile loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which can not only save time but makes for a more predictable execution environment.
- In your case, you can consolidate the multiple commands into a *single* one, using advanced regex techniques, combined with using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content) `-Raw` to read a text file *as a whole*, into a single, multi-line string:

```bash
powershell -noprofile -command "$test=(gc path.txt)+'\Subdirectory\Subdirectory\test.txt';$null=new-item -force $test -value ((gc -Raw -encoding utf8 $test) -replace '(?m)^(Wolf|Bird|Pig|Fox|Bear|Elephant|Monkey)=.*', '$1=True')"
```

Note the use of:

- the multi-line inline regex option, `(?m)`, which makes `^` (and (`$`) match the start (and end) of *each line*, which is necessary, because the file content is now provided as a *single, multi-line* string due to `Get-Content -Raw`, which is much faster than the default behavior of reading files *line by line*.

  - While use of the [`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) .NET API could speed up line-by-line reading, `Get-Content -Raw` is by far faster, on par with [`[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadAllText).
- regex *alternation* (`|`) to match any of the animal names (`Wolf|Bird|Pig|Fox|Bear|Elephant|Monkey`)
- a capture group (`(...)`) to capture whatever name matches,
- the reference to the captured name via `$1` in the substitution operand of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation.

Because the file content is read as a single, multi-line string, there's no need for an [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-String) call.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and in depth explanation! It's very much appreciated. Your solution works perfect! Thank you very much.